# how to retrieve the id in mongodb by giving the name in java

Tags: java, mongodb

I want to retrieve id of a record in mongodb collection by specifying the name.

That's what I tried by it returned the whole thing, but I just want the id. Any help?

```
DBCollection parameterTable = db.getCollection("configurationTable");
BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
        searchQuery.put("name", "data1");
        DBCursor cursor = parameterTable.find(searchQuery);
       while (cursor.hasNext()) {
           System.out.println(cursor.next());
       }
```

And that's what it returns:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5423d3ceccf213e6d265fc9c"} , "name" : "data1" , "created" : { "$date" : "2014-09-25T08:35:26.361Z"} , "timestamp" : { "$date" : "2014-09-25T08:35:26.361Z"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not much sure, yet to get the id you can do something like :

```
 cursor.next().get("_id");
```